# Adding and removing from set

Tags: python, set

Adding and removing elements in a set. I think logic seems right,but I don't know to get this code to work.
I get the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

The question is :

Input is a sequence of lines where the first line indicates which numbers are in the set initially. The second line indicates which numbers are removed from the set (if present). The third line indicates which numbers are added to the set (if not present already). The fourth line indicates which numbers are removed, the fifth indicates which numbers are added, and so on. The process stops when the line

END

was entered. Print the current contents of the set in the ascending order.

```py
s=set(input().split())
finished=False
while not finished:
    s1=input()
    if s1 != 'END':
        s2=input().split()
        s.remove(s2)
    else:
        finished=True
    if s2 !='END':
        s3=input().split()
        s.add(s3)
    else:
        finished=True
print(s)
```

```
input:
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6
10 7 3
5 8 
1 9
END

output must be:
2 4 5 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are searching for

```py
s=set(input().split())
finished=False
c = False                                       #Flag to check if it odd time or even time so we know to remove or add
while True:
    s1=input()                                  #Getting input from the user
    if s1 != 'END':
        if c:
            delete_values = s1.split()
            for deleting in delete_values:      #Loop to check the values we want to remove so we wont try to remove item that doesnt exist
                if deleting in s:
                    s.remove(deleting)
        else:
            s.add(*s1.split())                  #Adding all the values of the split using * unpacking
        c = not c
    else:                                       #Break the loop after end was inserted
        break
print(s)
```

Comment: Maybe some additional explanations/comments would be in place.